# Supervisor not works for laravel queue

Tags: laravel

Expectation:
Log entries in worker.log, like "server check finished."

Behavior:
No entries in laravel logfiles, no feedback that worker run.

By start the queue on terminal it works.
Debian Server with supervisord.

my kernel.php:

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();

    $schedule->job(new CheckServerStatusJob)
        ->evenInMaintenanceMode()
        ->everyMinute()
        ->after(function () {
            info('server check finished.');
        })
        ->onFailure(function () {
            info('server check failed.');
            exec('php artisan down');
        });
}
```

[image: supervisor conf for laravel]

[image: analyse outpu]

Log from Supervisor

```
    2022-10-20 09:21:32,015 INFO success: lv_two_01 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
    2022-10-20 09:21:32,016 INFO spawned: 'lv_two_02' with pid 6427
    2022-10-20 09:21:33,017 INFO success: lv_two_02 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
    2022-10-20 09:32:54,075 INFO waiting for lv_two_01 to stop
    2022-10-20 09:32:54,075 INFO waiting for lv_two_00 to stop
    2022-10-20 09:32:54,075 INFO waiting for lv_two_02 to stop
    2022-10-20 09:32:54,080 INFO stopped: lv_two_01 (exit status 0)
    2022-10-20 09:32:54,084 INFO stopped: lv_two_00 (exit status 0)
    2022-10-20 09:32:54,084 INFO stopped: lv_two_02 (exit status 0)
    2022-10-20 09:32:55,088 INFO spawned: 'lv_two_01' with pid 8404
    2022-10-20 09:32:55,090 INFO spawned: 'lv_two_00' with pid 8405
    2022-10-20 09:32:55,122 INFO spawned: 'lv_two_02' with pid 8406
    2022-10-20 09:32:56,123 INFO success: lv_two_01 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
    2022-10-20 09:32:56,124 INFO success: lv_two_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
    2022-10-20 09:32:56,124 INFO success: lv_two_02 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
    2022-10-20 09:32:58,789 INFO waiting for lv_two_01 to stop
    2022-10-20 09:32:58,789 INFO waiting for lv_two_00 to stop
    2022-10-20 09:32:58,789 INFO waiting for lv_two_02 to stop
    2022-10-20 09:32:58,793 INFO stopped: lv_two_02 (exit status 0)
    2022-10-20 09:32:58,793 INFO stopped: lv_two_01 (exit status 0)
    2022-10-20 09:32:58,793 INFO stopped: lv_two_00 (exit status 0)
    2022-10-20 09:33:04,566 INFO spawned: 'lv_two_01' with pid 8451
    2022-10-20 09:33:04,567 INFO spawned: 'lv_two_00' with pid 8452
    2022-10-20 09:33:04,569 INFO spawned: 'lv_two_02' with pid 8453
    2022-10-20 09:33:05,570 INFO success: lv_two_01 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
    2022-10-20 09:33:05,570 INFO success: lv_two_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
    2022-10-20 09:33:05,570 INFO success: lv_two_02 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```